# Configure & Run a VPN server

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I rent a VPS. I want to run a VPN server on it, using `openvpn`.

I installed `openvpn` this way:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

With the dependencies needed. However, I have to configure it...

There is only *one* file in `/etc/openvpn`:

```
user@server:~$ cat /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf 
#!/bin/bash
# 
# Parses DHCP options from openvpn to update resolv.conf
# To use set as 'up' and 'down' script in your openvpn *.conf:
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
#
# Used snippets of resolvconf script by Thomas Hood and Chris Hanson.
# Licensed under the GNU GPL.  See /usr/share/common-licenses/GPL. 
# 
# Example envs set from openvpn:
#
#     foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS X.Y.Z.132' 
#     foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS X.Y.Z.133'
#     foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DOMAIN be.bnc.ch'
#

[ -x /sbin/resolvconf ] || exit 0
[ "$script_type" ] || exit 0
[ "$dev" ] || exit 0

split_into_parts()
{
    part1="$1"
    part2="$2"
    part3="$3"
}

case "$script_type" in
  up)
    NMSRVRS=""
    SRCHS=""
    for optionvarname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        option="${!optionvarname}"
        echo "$option"
        split_into_parts $option
        if [ "$part1" = "dhcp-option" ] ; then
            if [ "$part2" = "DNS" ] ; then
                NMSRVRS="${NMSRVRS:+$NMSRVRS }$part3"
            elif [ "$part2" = "DOMAIN" ] ; then
                SRCHS="${SRCHS:+$SRCHS }$part3"
            fi
        fi
    done
    R=""
    [ "$SRCHS" ] && R="search $SRCHS
"
    for NS in $NMSRVRS ; do
            R="${R}nameserver $NS
"
    done
    echo -n "$R" | /sbin/resolvconf -a "${dev}.openvpn"
    ;;
  down)
    /sbin/resolvconf -d "${dev}.openvpn"
    ;;
esac
```

What should I do? *Every* tutorial I found were dealing with files I do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to `/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/` , where are located some example config files. You can copy `client.conf` for example to your `/etc/openvpn/` dir. Also , you should edit your `/etc/default/openvpn` and set `AUTOSTART=client`. This will bring your openvpn server up with config file `/etc/openvpn/client.conf` . Now you can go to your tutorials to configure it.

I hope this can help you.

Regards